# How to access <div data-v-... class='xxx'> content with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml, href

I have been trying to scrap some href from each game on [this page](https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1/). However I see that the hrefs I'm looking for are in `div`s of the following format: `<div data-v-40ac480c class="xxxx">`. I do not manage to access the content of those divs (i get "None" from res2 in the example bellow).

I also noticed that the webpage take some times to load and do not display the games and odds in the first seconds, thus my `requests.get()` might not get the right data. I have tried many things (timeout, sleep, HTMLSession, nest_asyncio) but can't find out how to do it.

System used: Jupiter Notebook, mac OS, safari 14.1.2.

Here is a sample code i used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

url='https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/'+'france/ligue-1/'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#time.sleep(5)

if not response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.status_code)
else:
    results_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
    res=results_page.find('div',{'class':'flex flex-col px-3 text-sm max-mm:px-0'}) 
    print(res.find_all('div'))
    res2=results_page.find('div',{'class':'flex hover:bg-[#f9e9cc] group border-l border-r border-black-borders'})
    print(res2)
```

A sample html code of the `div` I'm looking for with its `a` tag is the following:

```
<div data-v-40ac480c="" class="flex hover:bg-[#f9e9cc] group border-l border-r border-black-borders">
   <a data-v-40ac480c="" href="/soccer/france/ligue-1/lille-lyon-W63Isx24/" class="flex-col next-m:flex-row mobile-next-matches flex items-start next-m:items-center pb-3 next-m:pb-0 justify-start next-m:gap-3 pl-2 border-black-borders min-w-[0] w-full pt-1 next-m:pt-0">
```

Utimate goal: Manage to access the div content for each game displayed on the page, then find a `a` tag and get the href(link) of every games where i will then go get the betting odds.

Answer (score 0):

The page is dynamically rendered and the actual match info is inside a `<next-matches>` tag. You can use `view source` and search `W63Isx24` to find it. Keep in mind that, as `requests` module can't handle javascript, we're dealing with raw html page as seen in `view source`, not final page shown in browser.

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import json

url='https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/'+'france/ligue-1/'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if not response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.status_code)
else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    data = json.loads(soup.select_one('next-matches')[':comp-data'])
    matches = data['d']['rows']
    for match in matches:
        print(match['url'])
```

**Output**

```
/soccer/france/ligue-1/lille-lyon-W63Isx24/
/soccer/france/ligue-1/auxerre-rennes-be0jv3eC/
/soccer/france/ligue-1/brest-paris-sg-SYdRuGWG/
/soccer/france/ligue-1/clermont-lens-6a66pvIo/
...
```